# Fitting a nonlinear model with parameters to data in R

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I have the following equation:

keq = (q^(1+b))/((cp^n) * cPEG)

where b is defined as:

b = b0 exp(b1 * cPEG+b2 * cp0)

and cp is dependent on q and can be expressed as:

cp = cp0 - q

I have data for cPEG and q and would like to fit this equation to the data by finding the optimal parameter values for keq, n, b0, b1 and b2. cp0 is a constant that is also given.

What would be the best approach in R to do this?

Initially I tried to isolate q and use nls with initial guesses for the parameters but this didn't work out as I realized I couldn't isolate q since cp is dependent on q. I was however able to fit the logistic function through the data points using SSlogis or with the explicit equation with the plinear-random algorithm to visualize trends.

```
st1 <- data.frame(L = c(0.01,2), k = c(1,20), coa0 = c(0.01,1.5))
fit1 <- nls2(q1 ~ L/(1 + exp(-k * (coa1 - coa0))), 
             start = st1,
             control = nls.control(maxiter = 200),
             algorithm="plinear-random")
fit2 <- nls(q2 ~ SSlogis(coa2, Asym, xmid, scal), data = df2)
```